# Demuth's theorem in set theory

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, computability-theory

I am quite sure the following fact must have been known for set theorists, though I could not find it anywhere.

If $r$ is random over $L$ and $x\in L[r]\setminus L$, then there must be some real $r_0$ random over $L$ so that $r_0\in L[x]$ and $x\in L[r_0]$.

So where I could find it?

**Addition**

Monroe Eskew has given an answer to the question. I would like to explain the phenomenon from a recursion theory point of view.

As Jason pointed out, the result is corresponded to Demuth's theorem in recursion theory. Actually it can be proved by applying Demuth's argument.

Suppose that $r$ is random and $x\in L[r]\setminus L$. Then there is a condition $r\in p\Vdash x\mbox{ is a real}$. Since random forcing is c.c.c., we may in $L$ find a sequence $\{p^i_n\}_{i,n\in \omega}$ stronger than $p$ so that for every $n$, $\{p^i_n\}_{i\in \omega}$ is a maximal antichain below $p$ and each $p^i_n$ decides a value of $x$. Coding these condition and the relation $p^i_n\Vdash x(n)=j_i$ into a single real $z\in L$. Then $x\leq_T r_0\oplus z$ with a use function $f\in L[r]$. Then $f$ is dominated by a function $g\in L$. Now using these facts and applying Demuth's argument, we may obtain a real $r_0$ which is also $L$-random so that $x\oplus z\oplus g\equiv_T r_0\oplus z\oplus g$.

So $x\in L[r_0]$ and $r_0\in L[x]$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "random over $L$"? Is it "$(L,\mathbb P)$-generic" where $\mathbb P$ is Random (Solovay) forcing and $L$ is the constructible universe?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Since you added the computability theory tag I can't help pointing out the connection (as I see it) to algorithmic randomness:  Your question seems to be a set theoretic version of the following computability theoretic statement: "If $r$ is Martin-Löf random and $0<x\leq r$, then there exists a Martin-Löf random $r_0$ so that $r_0 \equiv x$."  If $\leq$ is truth-table reduction and $\equiv$ is Turing equivalence, this is a theorem of Demuth.

Comment: Well, you must know I am an expert on this.

Comment: I changed the title to something more specific; I am not sure it is chosen well though and you could change it using "edit". In any case please try to avoid extremely general titles like "Reference request"; some places the only thing of a question that is shown is its title and this thus should convey something somewhat specific about the question.

Comment: @LiangYu : Yes, I figured you knew this, but maybe someone else would find it interesting.

Comment: I was just kidding. Thanks for pointing out this.

Comment: @quid I made the title even more descriptive (hopefully)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if this specific claim is stated explicitly anywhere, but it follows from the more general discussion about intermediate extensions in Jech, page 247. If we take any $x \in L[r]$, then there is a complete subalgebra $A$ of the random algebra associated to $\dot{x}$, with the property that $L[x]=L[G_r \cap A]$. But any complete subalgebra of a measure algebra is also a measure algebra. So $A$ is isomorphic to random forcing.